# Bootstrap toggle sub menu flex column glitch from row to column on show

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

I made a submenu displayed in column when clicking on a button. The submenu is working and is shown in column, but there is a small glitch that show it in row during a second then switching it to a column.
Is there something missing in my code ?

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-6">
  <div class="card">
    <a class="p-0 text-decoration-none" data-toggle="collapse" href="#sub-menu" role="button">
      <h6 class="card-header"><i class="fa fa-folder mr-2"></i>Open sub-menu</h6>
    </a>
    <div id="sub-menu" class="collapse nav flex-column bg-transparent">
      <a class="nav-link btn btn-light mt-1 mb-1" href="#">First Link</a>
      <a class="nav-link btn btn-light mb-1" href="#">Second Link</a>
      <a class="nav-link btn btn-light mb-1" href="#">Third Link</a>
      <a class="nav-link btn btn-light mb-1" href="#">Forth Link</a>
      <a class="nav-link btn btn-light mb-1" href="#">Fifth Link</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is a fiddle of the example: https://jsfiddle.net/mp9007/4rm0fsvx/5/

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the `nav` class from the `#sub-menu` div. Probably the collapse and `.nav` are having style conflicts because `.nav` adds a `display: flex` to the element.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the block with the `nav` class in block with the class `collapse`:

```
<div id="sub-menu" class="collapse">
    <div class="nav flex-column bg-transparent">
        <a class="nav-link btn btn-light mt-1 mb-1" href="#">First Link</a>
        <a class="nav-link btn btn-light mb-1" href="#">Second Link</a>
        <a class="nav-link btn btn-light mb-1" href="#">Third Link</a>
        <a class="nav-link btn btn-light mb-1" href="#">Forth Link</a>
        <a class="nav-link btn btn-light mb-1" href="#">Fifth Link</a>
    </div>
</div>
```